# caps lock doesn't work while on Hebrew

Tags: 14.04, capslock, hebrew

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo-510s.
installed Hebrew keyboard.
when I'm in English everything work fine with the caps lock but when im switching to Hebrew so the caps lock stop working.

any one can help me fix it?
tried already to search in google and here for a solution but only found an unanswered post

Comment: Did you try shift+Caps Lock? I don't know about a Hebrew keyboard, but it is that way on a Japanese keyboard.

Comment: @user3169, thanks for answer. shift is working like it used to. 
but i want to use CAPS lock only and to be able to write capitals letter in english while im in a different language (e.g. Hebrew)

this always worked for me.. not only on ubuntu.. so it is some kind of a bug..

Comment: I meant hold the Shift key and press the Caps Lock key.

Comment: @user3169,   thanks for your kind help.
i manage to solve this by upgrading my system to 16.04 from 14.04. and now the caps lock is working like i wanted.